# ValueError: could not convert string to float: in django in my models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I try to create a simple rest api with django but when i migrate my model i get this error :

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1789, in get_prep_value
    return float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`


**The joke is : i have no field of type FloatField() in my model !!**

#### So someone could be help me, i give you the code below Thk !!

May be the problem could be come from the srializer.py but ...

my_api/model.py :

```
class Bucketlist(models.Model):
"""This class represents the bucketlist model."""
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True,default="")
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
    return "{}".format(self.name)

class Meta:
    """test for admin interface"""
    verbose_name_plural = "Ma list de courses"
```

my_api/Serializer.py :

```
class BucketlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

class Meta:
    """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
    model = Bucketlist
    fields = '__all__' # == fields = ('id', 'name', 'date_created', 'date_modified') 

    read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')
```

my_api/View.py :

```
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
"""This class defines the create behavior of our rest api."""
queryset = Bucketlist.objects.all()
serializer_class = BucketlistSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """Save the post data when creating a new bucketlist."""
    serializer.save()
```

my_api/Test.py :

```
class ViewTestCase(TestCase):
"""Test suite for the api views."""

def setUp(self):
    """Define the test client and other test variables."""
    self.client = APIClient()
    self.bucketlist_data = {'name': 'Go to Ibiza'}
    self.response = self.client.post(
        reverse('create'),
        self.bucketlist_data,
        format="json")

def test_api_can_create_a_bucketlist(self):
    """Test the api has bucket creation capability."""
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

my_api/url.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^bucketlists/$',views.CreateView.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r'^$', views.BucketlistView.as_view(), name ="list")
] urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: please post the complete error stack

Comment: float conversion may be being used for the DateTimeField, can you check what the data in the database looks like for those DateTimeField's?

Comment: i don't think that complete error stack are usefull